# Animate around a point - Raphael

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm trying to animate a triangle around a given point. I want the shape to animate using the corner (on the right hand side) as it's anchor point but at the moment I can only seem to get it to animate from what I think is it's center. How do I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/3LXXQ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add origin co-ordinates to the rotation transform.

```
path_p2.animate({transform: "r360,456.933,372.57"}, 2000);​
```

Here's your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/KKScz/)

Comment: I was just about to write the exact same answer.  Here's my update: http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/3LXXQ/1/